# Adding ngStyle along with native HTML inline Style tag in Angular 6

Tags: html, angular

I need to add style using ngStyle along with HTML style which is already applied.

```
<th style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-bottom:10px;" [ngStyle]='statusColor'></th>
```

And in TypeScript,

```
private statusColor:string;
```

But this is not working. Can't we add both HTML's Style and ngStyle in same tag? If we Can't do this, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: That won't be a problem, using `ngStyle` you can dynamically add styles based on condition. but what is `machineStatusColor` in your question?

Comment: That is variable name. I have edited to 'statuColor'. But this is not working.

Comment: Can you post some example string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `statusColor` is a string, then you need to do something like this

```
<th style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-bottom:10px;" 
[ngStyle]="{'color':statusColor}"></th>
```

Or you can use an object directly

**ts**

```
private myStyle = {color: statusColor};
```

**html**

```
<th style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-bottom:10px;"
 [ngStyle]='myStyle'></th>
```

(In this example the object is static though)